# How can I get NDSolve to use a disk file for working storage?

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve 16 time-dependent coupled differential equations using `NDSolve` and it is taking too much RAM, as a result, the code is not giving results. To overcome this, I want to write all the values of 16 variables to a text file while the `NDSolve` is executing and I want the code to read values back from the file, too. Please help me out with the syntax and other possibilities for faster processing.

This is the code I've written

```
γ = 6 10^6; γcol = 5 10^6;
Γ21 = 4 γ; Γ32 = 1 γ; Γ43 = 6 γ; Γ41 = 5 γ; Γ31 = 4 γ; Γ42 = 4 γ;
γ12 = 5 γ; γ13 = 5 γ; γ14 = 9 γ; γ34 = 8 γ; γ24 = 2 γ; γ23 = 7 γ;
Δp = 0; Δc = 0.; Δrf = 0.;
Ωp = 1 γ; Ωc = 4 γ; Ωrf = 6 γ; 
Ωrfconj = Ωrf; Ωpconj = Ωp; Ωcconj = Ωc;

eqs = NDSolve[{
  ρ44'[t] == -I Γ43 ρ44[t] - I Γ42 ρ44[t] - I Γ41 ρ44[t] + Ωrf ρ34[t] - Ωrfconj ρ43[t],
  ρ33'[t] == I Γ43  ρ44[t] - I Γ32 ρ33[t] - I Γ31 ρ33[t] - Ωrf ρ34[t] + Ωrfconj ρ43[t] + Ωc ρ23[t] - Ωcconj ρ32[t],
  ρ22'[t] == I Γ32 ρ33[t] + I Γ42 ρ44[t] - I Γ21 ρ22[t] - Ωc ρ23[t] + Ωcconj ρ32[t] + Ωp ρ12[t] - Ωpconj ρ21[t],
  ρ11'[t] == I Γ41 ρ44[t] + I Γ31 ρ33[t] + I Γ21 ρ22[t] - Ωp ρ12[t] + Ωpconj ρ21[t],
  ρ43'[t] == (Δrf - I γ34) ρ43[t] + Ωrf (ρ44[t] - ρ33[t]) - Ωcconj ρ42[t],
  ρ42'[t] == (Δc + Δrf - I γ24) ρ42[t] + Ωrf ρ32[t] - Ωcconj ρ43[t] + Ωp ρ41[t],
  ρ41'[t] == (Δp + Δc + Δrf -I γ14) ρ41[t] + Ωrf ρ31[t] - Ωpconj ρ42[t],
  ρ32'[t] == (Δc - I γ23) ρ32[t] + Ωc (ρ22[t] - ρ33[t]) + Ωrf ρ42[t] - Ωpconj ρ31[t],
  ρ31'[t] == (Δp + Δc - I γ13) ρ31[t] + Ωc ρ21[t] - Ωpconj ρ32[t] + Ωrf ρ41[t],
  ρ21'[t] == (Δp - I γ12) ρ21[t] + Ωp (ρ11[t] - ρ22[t]) + Ωc ρ31[t],
  ρ12'[t] == Conjugate[ρ21'[t]], ρ13'[t] == Conjugate[ρ31'[t]], ρ23'[t] == Conjugate[ρ32'[t]],
  ρ14'[t] == Conjugate[ρ41'[t]], ρ24'[t] == Conjugate[ρ42'[t]],ρ34'[t] == Conjugate[ρ43'[t]],
  ρ11[0] == 1.0, ρ22[0] == 0.0, ρ33[0] == 0.0, ρ44[0] == 0.0, 
  ρ12[0] == 0.0, ρ13[0] == 0.0, ρ14[0] == 0.0, ρ21[0] == 0.0, 
  ρ23[0] == 0.0, ρ24[0] == 0.0, ρ31[0] == 0.0, ρ32[0] == 0.0, 
  ρ34[0] == 0.0, ρ41[0] == 0.0, ρ42[0] == 0.0, ρ43[0] == 0.0}, 
  {ρ44, ρ33, ρ22, ρ11, ρ43, ρ42, ρ41, ρ32, ρ31, ρ34, ρ21, ρ24, ρ23, ρ12, ρ13, ρ14}, 
  {t, 0.0,10}, MaxSteps -> Automatic, MaxStepSize -> Automatic, Method -> Automatic, PrecisionGoal -> Automatic, AccuracyGoal -> Automatic];

Plot[Evaluate[{ρ11[t]} /. eqs[[1]], {t, 0, 10}], PlotRange -> {All, All}, PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}]
```

Comment: Please show us the specific code, or it's hard to give advice. The only thing I can say at the moment, is "write all the values of 16 variables to a text file within NDSolve command and want the code to read values from there" is probably the wrong way to go.

Comment: I have provided the code

Comment: The code is incomplete.

Comment: @Pacifier How are we supposed to evaluate the code without numerical values for the constants?

Comment: Can't reproduce the mentioned issue in _v9.0,1_ and _v11.2_. I only get `NDSolve::mxst` warning and the calculation stops at about `t=0.000024644009293555068`. Further check shows the solutions blow up at this moment, which seems to suggest something wrong with the equation system itself.

Comment: I also noticed this, can I change the step size of time inside NDSolve? Could you also please tell me how you checked the solutions? You mentioned "further check shows..." in your comment, it would help me in debugging my codes.

Comment: Well, the initial value problem solver for ODE system in `NDSolve` is quite robust i.e. the step size by default is usually the best. My "further check" is just plotting: `Plot[eqs[[1, All, -1]][t] // Through // Abs // Evaluate, {t, 0, 
  0.000024644009293555068}, PlotRange -> All]`

Answer (score 3):

Extended comment:

As @xzczd noted, the system grows quickly.  After reducing the maximum time to `0.00001`:

```
LogPlot[Evaluate[Re[ρ11[t]] /. eqs[[1]]], {t, 0, 0.00001}, PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It seems that the system is linear.  In that case, the general solution is the sum of exponentials, with growth rates depending on eigenvalues of the related Jacobian matrix.  (Well, the imaginary bits might complicate that, I never run into those in my own work).  You might be able to avoid `NDSolve` completely.

Comment: Then what are the other options other than NDSOlve? Can I write values in a text file within NDSolve command?

Comment: If you can reformulate your problem as a matrix, see (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation).  Then you'd use `Eigenvalues[]` to calculate the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$.  While your original question of saving the intermediate values of `NDSolve` to a file is interesting, I don't think it's the best solution to your problem, because with the parameter values you give, the solution diverges extremely quickly.  Is that the behavior you expect?

Comment: No, the solution should not diverge. The plot should be below the value 1 and should become constant as steady state reaches.

Comment: Hmm, then I suggest examining your equations and parameter values for typos.  Good luck!